# Latest method for getting "Sister Database" in mongodb

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-java

I've been using `com.mongodb.DB` in my previous projects upto now. Since, the `getDB()` method is deprecated and we use `getDatabase()` instead. We need to change `DB` class with `MongoDatabase` class for this to work(I guess?). The problem I'm facing with this class is, there is no `getSisterDabatase()` method found in this class. Does anyone know how to access "Sibling Database" using `MongoDatabse` class? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked db.getSiblingDB(name) ? Please specify your MongoDB version, JDK version and driver.
I am using driver mongodb driver 3+ and it has getSisterDB(name).

Comment: Java version:1.8.0_131        MongoDB version: 3.4.7 driver version: 3.5.0 yes I have checked... its not present

Comment: Can you upgrade drivers?